# Inequality to leading to Heisenberg's uncertainty

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to learn measure theory by myself mostly following Folland. As I try to study I came up with the following question which I could not get an answer by myself.

Given a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $f'\in L^2$, prove that

$$ \int \lvert f(x)\lvert^2 \leq 4 \int \lvert xf(x)\lvert^2 \int  \lvert f'(x)\lvert ^2. $$

I guess the solution has something to do with Fourier transforms and it also states this inequality can be generalized to Heisenberg's uncertainty.

Comment: If you want Fourier Methods, I could imagine Plancherel's Theorem being useful here

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}|f(x)|^2 = 2f'(x)f(x)
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\int |f(x)|^2\ dx = x|f(x)|^2\bigg|^\infty_{-\infty} - 2\int xf(x)f'(x)\ dx.
\end{align}
for any Schwartz function $f$.

Also, you probably forgot some square roots.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $f$ is Schwartz